# Problems with swapping

Tags: c++, algorithm, swap

I was solving a problem and the problem description was:

> Given a number N. You have to perform exactly two swap operations
> to make the number as large as possible.
>
> You are given a number N (10 ≤ N ≤ 2×10<sup>9</sup>). You have to perform exactly
> two swap operation. You may choose any two unequal positions of
> this number, and swap the digits at those two positions.
>
> Like, for number 451 you can choose position 1 and 2 then swap this
> after swapping number will 541 again you can choose position 2 and 3
> and swap after swapping number become 514.
>
> What is the largest number you can get after these two operations?

So I made a code which kind of makes sense but I can't understand why in my code `swap()` is swapping the same character. You may understand by seeing the code better.

```
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        ll k=2;//Number of minimum swaps
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
            char ma=s[i];//storing maximum number 
            for(int j=i+1;j<s.size();j++){
                if(ma < s[j]){
                    ma=s[j];
                }
            }
            if(ma != s[i]){
                swap(ma,s[i]);//swaping two chars if I found something bigger than s[i]. This line is also occuring error I mean unexpected behavior
                k--;
            }
            cout<<"Iteration "<<i+1<<" "<<s<<endl;//This line is for inspecting what is going on
        }
    }
}
```

Input and output:

```
Input:
1
123
Output:
Iteration 1 323
Iteration 2 333
Iteration 3 333
```

This shouldn't happen if you see the code.

Please say what is going on with `swap`.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but... if you just have to print the result, could you just sort the string?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @silverfox I can't sort because I to swap any two digits of the number

Comment: @fabian Sorry for that actually I forgot to edit.I has to be `ma` which will be swaped.But if I use `ma` instead of `c` then also the result is unexpected.

Comment: You're swapping a string element with a local variable, but you should be swapping two string elements. For instance, if you store `s[0]` in `ma` and then swap `ma` with `s[1]`, you still have the same value is `s[0]`. (Print `ma` as well as `s` to see what's going on.)

Comment: You are not stopping after `k` swaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @molbdnilo mentioned, your `ma` variable is only a **copy** of your `s[j]` char. To actually switch between those two chars, you need to use a temp variable to store the location of `j`

```
int jtmp;
for(int j=i+1;j<s.size();j++)
{
    if(ma < s[j])
    {
        ma=s[j]; jtmp = j;
    }
}
```

Full modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        ll k=2;
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            char ma=s[i]; int jtmp;
            for(int j=i+1;j<s.size();j++)
            {
                if(ma < s[j])
                {
                    ma=s[j]; jtmp = j;
                }
            }
            if(ma != s[i])
            {
                swap(s[jtmp],s[i]);
                k--;
            }
            cout<<"Iteration "<<i+1<<" "<<s<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1
45231
Iteration 1 54231
Iteration 2 54231
Iteration 3 54321
Iteration 4 54321
Iteration 5 54321
```

Addition : You can see that your loop still goes for a while after the string are sorted. This could be fixed with a function to check if the string has been sorted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

bool LF(char a, char b)
{
    return a > b;
}

bool stringCheck(string x)
{
    string y = x;
    sort(y.begin(), y.end(), LF);
    if (y == x) {return true;} return false;
}


int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        ll k=2;
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            char ma=s[i]; int jtmp;
            for(int j=i+1;j<s.size();j++)
            {
                if(ma < s[j])
                {
                    ma=s[j]; jtmp = j;
                }
            }
            if(ma != s[i])
            {
                swap(s[jtmp],s[i]);
                k--;
            }
            cout<<"Iteration "<<i+1<<" : "<<s<<endl;
            if (stringCheck(s)) {break;}
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1
45231
Iteration 1 : 54231
Iteration 2 : 54231
Iteration 3 : 54321
```

Comment: What happens when you try the input 12345, what is the value of k after that?

Comment: @Surt well it outputted 0, but I haven't noticed the `k` variable before...

Comment: Hmm 12345 wasn't a good test ... try with 15432, should output -2 for k, which exceed the allowed number of swaps. (51432, 54132, 54312, 54321)

Comment: @Surt ahh, I noticed that the OP said that `k` is for the maximum number of swap. But well, my answer is for the question of why `swap()` isn't working properly anyway